# invalid SOAP request needs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, savon

I'm using savon to make requests against a SOAP service.

Regardless, I'm having trouble making Savon client call.

below mentioned are my ruby code

```
client = Savon.client(
    wsdl: "https://<URL>",
    soap_header: { 'Content-Type:' => "text/xml"},
    log: true,    
    pretty_print_xml: true
)

client.call(:get_active_employees_info,:xmlns =>"http://tempuri.org/") do
  message("AppID" => "*******","Username" => "*****","Password" => "******")
end
```

which return

```
Savon::HTTPError: HTTP error (400)
```

but same snippets run on Postman

```
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetActiveEmployeesInfo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <AppID>**********</AppID>
      <Username>********</Username>
      <Password>**********</Password>
    </GetActiveEmployeesInfo>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Comment: Add a `log_level: :debug` option when you create the client, it should provide more info. Also, copy how you do the request with postman too to compare. You should inspect the request in both cases and look for diferences.

Comment: You don't need to use `soap_header` as per the posted envelop content, so try to remove it. Check here: http://savonrb.com/version2/globals.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is related to the request body that you are building.

Since you have a working example, I would start by checking the request's body build by savon. To do this, use the following code:

```
 ops = client.operation(:get_active_employees_info)
 puts ops.build(message: {"AppID" => "*******","Username" => "*****","Password" => "******"}).pretty
```

Then, compare generated message with the one from Postman. I hope it helps.